# ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::Error: ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, heroku

I got this error when call the function on heroku and can't figure out why causes it broken.
As you can see, the function is to create an value into echos table. 
Oddly, it works fine on my local development.
Below is my heroku log. Any idea???

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 13ms
>
> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_echos_on_user_id_and_yell_id"
>
> INSERT INTO "echos" ("created_at", "is_yell", "latitude", "longitude", "updated_at", "user_id", "yell_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "
>   id"):

---

I tried `validates_uniqueness_of` but it still didn't work.

```
class Echo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :yell

  attr_accessible :user_id, :yell_id, :longitude, :latitude, :is_yell 
  validates_uniqueness_of :is_yell, :scope => [:yell_id, :user_id]
  validates :user_id, :yell_id, :presence => true
end

# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: echos
#
#  id         :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  is_yell    :boolean(1)
#  user_id    :integer
#  yell_id    :integer
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#
```

Answer (score 0):

Your uniqueness constraint permits `(user_id,yell_id,is_yell)` `(1,1,true)` and `(1,1,false)`, while the `UNIQUE` index would reject this set of rows. I don't know which is correct for your application.

If the index is proper (at most one row for any `user_id, yell_id` combination), then you should change your validation:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :yell_id, :scope => :user_id
```

If the current validation is proper (permitting both a yell and non-yell with the same `user_id, yell_id`), then you should drop the index and create a new one:

```
remove_index :echo, [:user_id,:yell_id], :unique => true    
add_index :echo, [:user_id,:yell_id,:is_yell], :unique => true
```

Answer (score 0):

im prety sure you are making a non callback sql, like update_all, this won't run the validations, so you need to catch the error and handle it

Answer (score -1):

What if you try to avoid save duplicates before database update query? I mean, use "validates_uniqueness_of" on Echo model.

Are you doing this? could you paste the source code of Echo model here or in gist?

Regards.

Comment: I updated my echo model with validates_uniqueness_of but same problem. Run fine on dev but broken on heroku prod